# asp.net Dynamic Data Site and SQL Server image datatype

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, dynamic-data

I'm just now created Dynamic Data Entities Web Site. 
And I have got a problem with image type. for all sql data types generated html elements by fieldTemplate. So, how can I create fieldtemplate for image-view, and image-upload  ?